# Uk visa refused as self employed

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

How Do i mitigate my UK visa refusal, though i attached my company registration documents, income tax returns, invoice and receipts. Second paragraph was a mistake as i did not state anything like that

---

[image]

Though I attached to my application my company's registration documents, income tax return, invoices, contract agreement with my staffs, –

Edited in from an almost identical question, which is now closed:
What do I need to do to re-apply again? Though paragraph 2 was a mistake from the visa officers because I didn't state anything like that.

Comment: Can you post your refusal notice, with personal details blanked out? If UKVI have made a material error in deciding on your application, you should reapply, pointing out their mistake.

Comment: @Kwame UKVI want evidence that your business is trading at a profit sufficient to justify the income you stated. This would typically be eg trading accounts certified by a qualified accountant.

Comment: @Traveller what is trading accounts?

Comment: @Tomas By my business is commercial transport of passengers from one place to the other

Comment: @Kwame Typically, income statements that detail profit or loss during a specific period of time and balance sheets that outline the business’ assets and liabilities. You should also supply your business’ bank statements as well as your personal bank statements.